# Using `Compare` object with C++ set in cython

Tags: set, std, cython

I would like to define a comparison method for a C++ `set` from python. In particular, I have a struct together with a `set`

```
from libcpp.set cimport set as cppset

ctypedef packed struct MyObject:
    int value

cdef cppset[MyObject*] myset
```

In standard C++, I can define a [`Compare`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/key_comp/) object with which I can impose a particular order on the set (e.g. using the `value` property of the object). Can I achieve the same in cython?

Comment: 1) you know you're defining a set of pointers not of objects? That's isn't hugely conventional. 2) I don't think you can easily; you could try specializing `std::less`, but that might have consequences elsewhere?

Comment: Yes, happy with having pointers. I'll try using a `cdef cppclass` and overwrite the comparison operator.

Comment: I often think in cases like this it's easiest to write a small amount of extra c++ code rather than trying to do it in Cython (where the c++ code generation is imperfect). I'm not really sure how to apply that idea to your problem though...